# How to add a request identifier to OWIN requests using Serilog?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, serilog, owin-middleware

I'm trying to get the same as with using [SerilogWeb.Classic.WebApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SerilogWeb.Classic.WebApi/) using this:

```
app.Use(async (owinContext, next) =>
{
    using (Serilog.Context.LogContext.PushProperty("HttpRequestId", Guid.NewGuid()))
    {
        await next();
    }
});
```

and this template

```
{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {HttpRequestId}: {SourceContext}: {Message} {Scope}{NewLine}{Exception}
```

But `HtpRequestId` always comes up empty in the log:

```
2017-09-18 23:26:13.056013 +01:00 [WRN] : <SourceContext>: <message>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added `Enrich.FromLogContext()` to your Serilog configuration? This opt-in is required before ambient contextual properties will be picked up and added to events.

Comment: That was what I was missing.